# SQL extract total number of instances of a substring in an array in JSON fields

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, json-query

How can I get a SQL Query to go within the JSON of a Column, and find the number of instances of a substring within that entire Column?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

i.e

```
FruitPageTable
[Id, PageData (nvarchar(max))]
[1 , [{"id":"0","Url":"/i-like-apples/ok-cool"}, {"id":"1","Url":"/where-are-apples/nowhere"} ] 
[2 , [{"id":"0","Url":"/where-are-oranges/everywhere"}]
[3 , [{"id":"0","Url":"/where-are-apples/somewhere"}]
[4 , [{"id":"0","Url":"/apples"},{"id":"1","Url":"/yay-apples"},{"id":"2","Url":"/apples"}]
```

So

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM FruitPageTable
WHERE [PageData] LIKE '%apples%'`

gives me 3...i.e the amount of records that have 'apples' in it.

But how to I get the count of 'apples' in the `Url` property within the JSON in `PageData`, across all records? i.e 6 mentions in total.
Is there some syntax with JSON_QUERY that I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need `json_query` to check number of `'apples'`, `string` and `mathematical` functions will do this.

```
select
  sum(round((length(val) - length(replace(val, 'apples', '')))/length('apples'))) AS count    
from
  MySQLTable
```

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWif2AAexHAVMFKzxjYeoz/0#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)

**sqlserver**, use `openjson`

```
select count(1) from
MySQLTable t1
cross apply openjson(t1.val)
with (
   url varchar(200) '$.Url'
) as i
where url like '%apples%'
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c5b2/1)

Comment: I'm specifically wanting to look within the Url Json property though. i.e imagine there was a third column called fruitType, of which 'apples' could be mentioned.... I don't want that to be included in the Count.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby, what mysql version you are using?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2016. Updated the question. Sorry if the 'MySQLTable' name in my example suggested a MySQL database.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby, sql server use openjson, see updated answer